# Font Error SFML

Tags: c++, mingw, sfml

I'm trying to make a game using SFML, and am currently in the loading text stage. I'm using the mingw compiler in order to compile my program, but when i compile it I get this error

undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf4Font12loadFromFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE'

The font file is in the same folder as the code.

Here is my code.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(),"Hello Window");
   sf::Font font;
   if(!font.loadFromFile("bit.ttf"))
   {
       std::cout << "No Work";
   }
   sf::Text text("hello", font);
   text.setCharacterSize(30);
   text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
   text.setColor(sf::Color::Red);
    while(Window.isOpen())
    {

      sf::Event Event;
      while(Window.pollEvent(Event))
      {

          if(Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
          {

              Window.close();
          }

      }

      // Declare and load a font


// Create a text

// Draw it
      Window.draw(text);
      Window.clear(sf::Color());
      Window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not linking with a sfml library. It has nothing to do with your font.

Comment: how would i do that was basically my question

Answer (score 0):

You have a linker error. To resolve this, you need to find the SFML dll's and paste them into your executable folder, or alternatively add the path to them to the PATH environment variable. See [this](http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path) for information on how to do that.

Next, you have to make sure that you are adding the correct .lib files to your linker input. Information on how to do that in Visual Studio can be found [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php). For other IDE's, you can take a look at [this](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/) page.

Comment: Well in mingw the program compiles when the font is commented out, and I already added the SFML dlls, here is my compile statement. g++ %file% -IC:\Development\SFML-2.3.1\include -LC:\Development\SFML-2.3.1\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -o %exe%

Comment: I use Mingw fyi so I don't have an IDE

Comment: I would recommend you get one, like Visual Studio. Linking libraries becomes much easier that way, and you have a nice coding environment.